# Yahoo-Pipes Throttles Requests: What are the limits?

Tags: yahoo-pipes, throttling

Yesterday, I began encountering '999' errors on Yahoo-Pipes. It looks like they throttle requests from a given IP address.

> Does anyone know the Yahoo-Pipes' requests per minute limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - 200 runs (of a given Pipe) in 10 minutes.
> - 200 runs (of any Pipe) from an IP in 10 minutes.
> - If you exceed the 200 runs in a 10 minute block, your Pipe will be 999'ed for a hour.

Comment: please dont use tinyurl on a site like this - theres no reason to

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Yahoo hasn't published any documentation on their limits yet.

The [troubleshooting guide](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs?doc=troubleshooting#q11) is vague:

> Why am I getting "999 Errors" from
>   pipes.yahoo.com? A 999 error implies
>   you are over utilizing our service.
>
> Please try throttling back the number
>   of requests made to the Pipes site and
>   within a few hours you should no
>   longer be blocked.
>
> The Pipes team puts these measures in
>   place to protect the overall
>   experience for its users. If you think
>   the amount of traffic you are sending
>   to the Pipes site should be allowed
>   and would like to make more requests
>   than normal, please contact our
>   Business Development team at: pipes-bd
>   [at] yahoo-inc.com.

However, I did find a [Pipes developer forum post](http://discuss.pipes.yahoo.com/Message_Boards_for_Pipes/threadview?bn=pip-DeveloperHelp&tid=9850&mid=9852) posted on July 31 which indicates forthcoming documentation:

> Hi,
>
> You'll have to hang on for an hour or
>   so before your IP gets unblocked.
>
> We're going to create a doc on the
>   rate limits, i'll post back here when
>   we have more info about it.
>
> Thanks -Paul Pipes Team